# How to display data on top of <td> tag inner table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How to display data on top of `<td>` tag inner table?

By below code, when load page it will be show like this image:

http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ir/160521040137.png

But I want to show `111` on top of `<td>` tag, like this image:

http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/io/160521040244.png

How can I do that?  I tried every thing but it does not work.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;-ms-word-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-word;word-break: break-word;word-break: break-all;padding-left: 10px;border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;text-align: center;">111</td>
            <td style="width: 600px; -ms-word-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; -ms-word-break: break-word; word-break: break-word; word-break: break-all; padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; ">
dsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdfdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdfdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdf
            </td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;-ms-word-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-word;word-break: break-word;word-break: break-all;padding-left: 10px;border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;text-align: center;">222</td>
            <td style="width: 600px; -ms-word-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; -ms-word-break: break-word; word-break: break-word; word-break: break-all; padding-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; ">
dsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdhgdffdsgfdh
            </td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, don't use `-ms-word-wrap`. IE itself uses `word-wrap` and no other browser supports the `-ms-` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align:top;` and you're good to go.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ckae2m6/) with this addition.

Edit: Put those inline code inside a class and use it!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
 <td style="...; vertical-align: top;">...</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do it with adding `CSS` class

```
table td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; 
}
```

this can helps to code once and do for all `<TD>...</TD>` of table.